# Compile Java for :react-native-firebase:compileDebugJavaWithJavac 712 ms

Tags: react-native

```
//mainapplication.java

package 'com.ruci';
import android.app.Application;
import 'com.facebook.react.ReactApplication';
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage';
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
...
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new RNFirebasePackage(),
            new RNCWebViewPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new RNSharePackage(),
            new ReanimatedPackage(),
            new RNMail(),
            new RNCardViewPackage(),
            new RNAdMobPackage(),
            new LottiePackage()
      );
    }
```

... 
        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };
    ...
      @Override
      public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
      }
    ...
      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this,  false);
      }
    }

Comment: And what is your error?

Answer (score 0):

You havent described the problem you are facing, you have just posted the error snippet. We cant figure out what and when has happened. Next time be more clear, but as per the error i guess you have error when building apk .  Can you try installing the below things and then clean the gradle and try rebuilding it ?

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier
npx jetify
```